# node.js expressjs pattern match not equal

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using expressjs with node and running both https and http.

I want to require that all routes for `/secure/*` use https.  This is done:

```
app.all("/secure/*", function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.connection.encrypted) {
        res.redirect("https://" + req.headers["host"].replace(new RegExp(config.http_port, "g"), config.https_port) + req.url); 
    } else {
        return next();
    };
});
```

However, I also want to require that all routes that are not using `/secure/*` and try to access https, are redirected using the same method to http.

I tried doing this:

```
app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    if (req.connection.encrypted) {
        res.redirect("http://" + req.headers["host"].replace(new RegExp(config.https_port, "g"), config.http_port) + req.url); 
    } else {
        return next();
    };
});
```

But I end up in a redirect loop when accessing the https pages.  Is there a way to specify all routes, except those with `/secure/*` ?

Thank you!

Comment: In the second redirect, shouldn't you only redirect non-`/secure/*` requests to `http://`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is:

```
app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.connection.encrypted && !/^\/secure/.test(req.url)) {
        res.redirect("http://" + req.headers["host"].replace(new RegExp(config.https_port, "g"), config.http_port) + req.url); 
    } else {
        return next();
    };
});
```

Only do the redirect if the URL doesn't start with `/secure`.

However, I'd propose that instead of the redundant 'secure' label in the URLs, just mark certain paths as `requireHTTP` or `requireHTTPS`. You know you can pass multiple methods into `app.get` and other such router methods, right? Assuming you define `requireHTTP` and `requireHTTPS` (which would be identical to your original functions), you'd just do:

```
app.get("/path/to/keep/encrypted", requireHTTPS, function(req, res) {
    // Rest of controller
});

app.get("/path/to/keep/public", requireHTTP, function(req, res) {
    // Rest of controller
});

app.get("/path/you/dont/care/about/encryption/status", function(req, res) {
    // Rest of controller
});
```

That should do it.